# Mouseover on SVG to change color

Tags: html, css, svg

I added a SVG into my HTML. What I want to do is, when the mouse is hovering the SVG, change it to a yellowish color with transition of 1s.

The CSS in the HTML is:

```
.svg {
    width: 17px;
    height: 99px;
}
```

The content in HTML:

```
<body>
<img src="raptor.svg" class="svg" />
</body>
```

The **raptor.svg** content is as follow:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 17.17 99.37">
    <style>
    #content path {
        fill: #F00;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    #content:hover path {
        fill: #E2C650;
    }
    </style>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
        <g id="content">
            <path class="characters" d="M.34,99.37V92.43a8,8,0,0,1,1.41-4.88A4.9,4.9,0,0,1,6,85.64a5.31,5.31,0,0,1,2.56.59,5,5,0,0,1,1.81,1.64l6.5-3.64v5.12L11.64,92V95h5.19v4.41Zm3.47-6.79V95H8.17V92.53a2.34,2.34,0,0,0-.62-1.67A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,6,90.2a2,2,0,0,0-1.61.62A2.57,2.57,0,0,0,3.81,92.58Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M.34,73.15,16.64,67l.44,4.34-3.49,1.19v5.7l3.25,1.14v4.39L.34,77.56Zm5.29,2.28L10.11,77V73.78Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M16.83,60.39v4.41H.34V57.87A8.55,8.55,0,0,1,1,54.44,5.55,5.55,0,0,1,3,52a5.69,5.69,0,0,1,3.26-.91,5.18,5.18,0,0,1,3.19,1,5.78,5.78,0,0,1,1.93,2.56A9.28,9.28,0,0,1,12,58.06v2.33ZM3.81,58v2.38H8.56V58a2.27,2.27,0,0,0-.65-1.67,2.21,2.21,0,0,0-1.63-.65,2.51,2.51,0,0,0-1.79.64A2.27,2.27,0,0,0,3.81,58Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M3.81,35.82v5.26h13V45.5h-13v4.85H.34V36.23Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M0,26.34a8.92,8.92,0,0,1,1.12-4.55,7.58,7.58,0,0,1,3.06-3,9.06,9.06,0,0,1,4.32-1A9.24,9.24,0,0,1,13,18.88a7.74,7.74,0,0,1,3.08,3,8.82,8.82,0,0,1,1.1,4.44A8.75,8.75,0,0,1,16,30.84a7.74,7.74,0,0,1-3.07,3,9,9,0,0,1-4.32,1,9.1,9.1,0,0,1-4.48-1.09,7.82,7.82,0,0,1-3.08-3A8.72,8.72,0,0,1,0,26.34Zm8.63,4a5.52,5.52,0,0,0,3.49-1.06,3.47,3.47,0,0,0,1.36-2.9,3.67,3.67,0,0,0-1.3-2.9,5.47,5.47,0,0,0-3.7-1.13A5.35,5.35,0,0,0,5,23.42a3.7,3.7,0,0,0-.73,4.9,4.34,4.34,0,0,0,1.75,1.46A5.86,5.86,0,0,0,8.63,30.32Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M.34,15.13V8.2A8,8,0,0,1,1.75,3.32,4.9,4.9,0,0,1,6,1.41,5.31,5.31,0,0,1,8.53,2a5,5,0,0,1,1.81,1.64L16.83,0V5.12L11.64,7.79v2.93h5.19v4.41ZM3.81,8.34v2.38H8.17V8.29a2.34,2.34,0,0,0-.62-1.67A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,6,6a2,2,0,0,0-1.61.62A2.57,2.57,0,0,0,3.81,8.34Z" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Alternatively, I tried to use CSS to change the color during mouse over:

```
.svg:hover {
    color: #E2C650;
}
```

It's not working as well, as `color` CSS property cannot change the SVG fill color.

What did I miss? Do I have to use inline SVG instead?

Comment: Have you tried `fill` instead of color?

Comment: you can't do that with an <img>. <img> contents are not interactive. You'd need to put the SVG inline or use an <object> or <iframe> tag instead of an <img> tag.

Comment: @ntgCleaner `fill` is not a CSS property for HTML, it's for SVG. I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: As suggested in linked answer, best resource to learn and compare all currently known approaches to this problem, see comprehensive article at CSS tricks: https://css-tricks.com/change-color-of-svg-on-hover/ and `filter` possibilities. You can apply it at image as well as at background.

Comment: @Raptor, Correct.  If you want the `SVG` to change `fill` color, you need to use `fill` to change the color.

Comment: @Raptor You need to to go down to the path level `svg path { fill: red; }` -  Oh also, as @robertLongson said, you can't do anything with it if it's in an <img> tag

Comment: .. or you can use `filter` to turn all black areas from any image to for example red: `img {filter: invert(13%) sepia(69%) saturate(5718%) hue-rotate(356deg) brightness(122%) contrast(122%);}` -- computations from https://codepen.io/sosuke/full/Pjoqqp

Comment: @myf smart choice. I'm also considering to use Google Fonts + transform; just worry about the browser compatibility...

Comment: @Raptor yes, using real text rotated with CSS would most probably be the best option in general, because support for transforms is more than sufficient nowadays; I'd guess you don't even necessarily need webfont: just look at system font stacks built around Arial Black / Impact or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather using svg in img tag you can use place svg in DOM. This should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    svg {
      width: 17px;
      height: 99px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 17.17 99.37">
    <style>
    #content path {
        fill: #F00;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    #content:hover path {
        fill: #E2C650;
    }
    </style>
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
        <g id="content">
            <path class="characters" d="M.34,99.37V92.43a8,8,0,0,1,1.41-4.88A4.9,4.9,0,0,1,6,85.64a5.31,5.31,0,0,1,2.56.59,5,5,0,0,1,1.81,1.64l6.5-3.64v5.12L11.64,92V95h5.19v4.41Zm3.47-6.79V95H8.17V92.53a2.34,2.34,0,0,0-.62-1.67A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,6,90.2a2,2,0,0,0-1.61.62A2.57,2.57,0,0,0,3.81,92.58Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M.34,73.15,16.64,67l.44,4.34-3.49,1.19v5.7l3.25,1.14v4.39L.34,77.56Zm5.29,2.28L10.11,77V73.78Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M16.83,60.39v4.41H.34V57.87A8.55,8.55,0,0,1,1,54.44,5.55,5.55,0,0,1,3,52a5.69,5.69,0,0,1,3.26-.91,5.18,5.18,0,0,1,3.19,1,5.78,5.78,0,0,1,1.93,2.56A9.28,9.28,0,0,1,12,58.06v2.33ZM3.81,58v2.38H8.56V58a2.27,2.27,0,0,0-.65-1.67,2.21,2.21,0,0,0-1.63-.65,2.51,2.51,0,0,0-1.79.64A2.27,2.27,0,0,0,3.81,58Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M3.81,35.82v5.26h13V45.5h-13v4.85H.34V36.23Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M0,26.34a8.92,8.92,0,0,1,1.12-4.55,7.58,7.58,0,0,1,3.06-3,9.06,9.06,0,0,1,4.32-1A9.24,9.24,0,0,1,13,18.88a7.74,7.74,0,0,1,3.08,3,8.82,8.82,0,0,1,1.1,4.44A8.75,8.75,0,0,1,16,30.84a7.74,7.74,0,0,1-3.07,3,9,9,0,0,1-4.32,1,9.1,9.1,0,0,1-4.48-1.09,7.82,7.82,0,0,1-3.08-3A8.72,8.72,0,0,1,0,26.34Zm8.63,4a5.52,5.52,0,0,0,3.49-1.06,3.47,3.47,0,0,0,1.36-2.9,3.67,3.67,0,0,0-1.3-2.9,5.47,5.47,0,0,0-3.7-1.13A5.35,5.35,0,0,0,5,23.42a3.7,3.7,0,0,0-.73,4.9,4.34,4.34,0,0,0,1.75,1.46A5.86,5.86,0,0,0,8.63,30.32Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M.34,15.13V8.2A8,8,0,0,1,1.75,3.32,4.9,4.9,0,0,1,6,1.41,5.31,5.31,0,0,1,8.53,2a5,5,0,0,1,1.81,1.64L16.83,0V5.12L11.64,7.79v2.93h5.19v4.41ZM3.81,8.34v2.38H8.17V8.29a2.34,2.34,0,0,0-.62-1.67A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,6,6a2,2,0,0,0-1.61.62A2.57,2.57,0,0,0,3.81,8.34Z" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried to avoid using inline SVG, as it will make the HTML content messy. Yet seems I have no choice.

Comment: @Raptor you can use <object> or <iframe>

Answer (score 1):

I can see this working quite happily if you hover over any part of the SVG `path`.

If you want to also cause the transition when hovering over *any part of the SVG itself*, and not just the path then add the following CSS:

```
svg:hover #content path {
  fill: #E2C650;
}
```

Here's a working snippet:

```css
svg {
  width: 17px;
  height: 99px;
}

svg:hover #content path {
    fill: #E2C650;
}

#content path {
    fill: #F00;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 17.17 99.37">
    <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
        <g id="content">
            <path class="characters" d="M.34,99.37V92.43a8,8,0,0,1,1.41-4.88A4.9,4.9,0,0,1,6,85.64a5.31,5.31,0,0,1,2.56.59,5,5,0,0,1,1.81,1.64l6.5-3.64v5.12L11.64,92V95h5.19v4.41Zm3.47-6.79V95H8.17V92.53a2.34,2.34,0,0,0-.62-1.67A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,6,90.2a2,2,0,0,0-1.61.62A2.57,2.57,0,0,0,3.81,92.58Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M.34,73.15,16.64,67l.44,4.34-3.49,1.19v5.7l3.25,1.14v4.39L.34,77.56Zm5.29,2.28L10.11,77V73.78Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M16.83,60.39v4.41H.34V57.87A8.55,8.55,0,0,1,1,54.44,5.55,5.55,0,0,1,3,52a5.69,5.69,0,0,1,3.26-.91,5.18,5.18,0,0,1,3.19,1,5.78,5.78,0,0,1,1.93,2.56A9.28,9.28,0,0,1,12,58.06v2.33ZM3.81,58v2.38H8.56V58a2.27,2.27,0,0,0-.65-1.67,2.21,2.21,0,0,0-1.63-.65,2.51,2.51,0,0,0-1.79.64A2.27,2.27,0,0,0,3.81,58Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M3.81,35.82v5.26h13V45.5h-13v4.85H.34V36.23Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M0,26.34a8.92,8.92,0,0,1,1.12-4.55,7.58,7.58,0,0,1,3.06-3,9.06,9.06,0,0,1,4.32-1A9.24,9.24,0,0,1,13,18.88a7.74,7.74,0,0,1,3.08,3,8.82,8.82,0,0,1,1.1,4.44A8.75,8.75,0,0,1,16,30.84a7.74,7.74,0,0,1-3.07,3,9,9,0,0,1-4.32,1,9.1,9.1,0,0,1-4.48-1.09,7.82,7.82,0,0,1-3.08-3A8.72,8.72,0,0,1,0,26.34Zm8.63,4a5.52,5.52,0,0,0,3.49-1.06,3.47,3.47,0,0,0,1.36-2.9,3.67,3.67,0,0,0-1.3-2.9,5.47,5.47,0,0,0-3.7-1.13A5.35,5.35,0,0,0,5,23.42a3.7,3.7,0,0,0-.73,4.9,4.34,4.34,0,0,0,1.75,1.46A5.86,5.86,0,0,0,8.63,30.32Z" />
            <path class="characters" d="M.34,15.13V8.2A8,8,0,0,1,1.75,3.32,4.9,4.9,0,0,1,6,1.41,5.31,5.31,0,0,1,8.53,2a5,5,0,0,1,1.81,1.64L16.83,0V5.12L11.64,7.79v2.93h5.19v4.41ZM3.81,8.34v2.38H8.17V8.29a2.34,2.34,0,0,0-.62-1.67A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,6,6a2,2,0,0,0-1.61.62A2.57,2.57,0,0,0,3.81,8.34Z" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but this only works if the SVG is added to HTML inline.